# Using Spring Integration as a glue between spring beans

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a web application with controllers, services and simple beans.
I want to use Spring Integration as a glue to link the beans. So instead of using a reference to the next bean to be called in a bean I just want to send (return) a message (e.g. a domain object) which would be the incoming parameter in the method signature of the next bean.
Is it a good idea to use Spring Integration for this? Would SI degrade the performance?

Thanks,
V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, read the Reference Manual (http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) and other resources before asking similar questions. Spring Integration isn't a glue.

It's an Enterprise Integration Patterns implementation Framework. Even if it can do what you are asking, its purpose is much farther.

I'd say such a requirements may be addressed just with the raw `ApplicationEvent` model.